# Exhibiting the relationship between hylo and hyloM

Tags: haskell, recursion-schemes

I'm told the following functions are equivalent in power

```
hylo :: Functor f => (f b -> b) -> (a -> f a) -> a -> b
hylo f g = h where h = f . fmap h . g

hyloM :: (Traversable g, Monad m) => (g b -> m b) -> (a -> m (g a)) -> a -> m b
hyloM f g = h where h = f <=< traverse h <=< g
```

For the life of me, though, I can't figure out how to demonstrate this. Setting Monad to Identity in hyloM gets pretty much the right thing, but g is `Traversable` not `Functor`, and I have tried a number of approaches to go from hylo to hyloM with no success.

Are these isomorphic, or at least similar in power? If so, how do I evidence that?

Comment: What does it mean for them to be equivalent in power, if they work on different types? The only meaning I could understand would be "hylo can be implemented in terms of hyloM, and vice versa, using some translation between the types involved".

Comment: Exactly that. I think the answer given plus the comments exhibits the "nearly isomorphism". It would be nice if they were exactly isomorphic, but I think hyloM needs modification for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define `hyloM` using `hylo` by instantiating `f = Compose m g`.

```
hyloM' :: (Traversable g, Monad m) => (g b -> m b) -> (a -> m (g a)) -> a -> m b
hyloM' f g = hylo (\(Compose mg) -> mg >>= sequence >>= f) (\a -> Compose (g a))
```

I'm not sure about the converse.

Comment: I think the converse is either trivial (making `m ~ Identity`, if you don't mind adding the `Traversable` constraint) or impossible (if you do mind adding the constraint).

Comment: Yeah, if you parameterise by the traversal function it's easy enough to swap f Identity to Identity f though, so maybe it's only equivalent to "gHyloM"